# Condition for key value

Tags: python

I have dictionary like this:

```
emp_rec1 = {
        "name":"Mr.Geek",
        "eid":24,
        "location":"delhi"
        }
```

I want to write condition for it

```
If name=Mr.Geek
then prnit (hello)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you adding how to index a dictionary in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access value for key using `emp_rec1['name']` and compare it using `==`

```
In [10]: emp_rec1 = {
    ...:         "name":"Mr.Geek",
    ...:         "eid":24,
    ...:         "location":"delhi"
    ...:         }

In [11]: if emp_rec1['name'] == 'Mr.Geek':
    ...:     print('hello')
    ...:
hello

In [12]:
```

If you are unsure about key in dict you can use [**.get**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of dict.

like,

```
emp_rec1.get('name') == 'Mr.Geek'
```